defref a lifetime value from a none lifetime value
Can I write some code to get a lifetime value deref from a none lifetime value ?

struct A {
 x: String,
}

struct B<'a> {
 y: &'a str,
}

impl Deref for A {
  type Target = B;
  fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
    &B{y: &self.x}
  }
}


Not really, and that's a big deficiency of Deref: the stuff you're referencing must be stored in the object verbatim (or statically, of course). Your B, despite only consisting of references into A, is not itself stored in A (or statically), so it cannot be a valid Deref target. You'll need to find another way to achieve what you're after.

If Deref were designed today, it'd probably make use of generic associated traits to define type Target<'a> and fn deref(&'a self) -> Self::Target<'a>, which would allow you to specify either a reference or a type such as B<'a> as target. But in the current design where deref() returns an actual reference, your hands are tied.

Thanks for your explain. actually , I need to create a trait Store to impl some database actions,  the store could be a transaction store or a basic db store, so I need a MysqlStore contains conn: MysqlConnection , when directly call db query, and I also need a MysqlAction contains conn: &mut MysqlConnection( this because MysqlConnection.trasaction() returns a &mut MysqlTrasaction) to impl trait Store , outside the store crate can use some thing like mysqlStroe.getSomeThing() or mysqlStore.tx(|store|{store.getSomeThing()}) . I don't know hot to impl this.

You should expand that comment into a (separate) question, and add additional details on how you'd like to use the type. Getting it right might be somewhat harder than it looks at first, but it should be possible.

@user4815162342 seeing that Deref[Mut] is designed exclusively for smart pointers, I don't think it would be implemented differently today.
